# Rails Model - Confirm Email Address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 app I have an email field. My model ensures that no duplicate values are stored using the following:

```
validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

This has served me well while I wasn't bothered about confirming email addresses but now I want to confirm them before they are able to login. This means that I only want to confirm uniqueness if another field `confirmed` is true.

Is there an in-built way to tackle this at all or will it be my own validation rule that's required?

Comment: I would recommend the use of a gem like "devise" to  solve your whole auth logic..

Comment: Quite happy making my own thanks

Comment: Any particular reason you're rolling your own auth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass options such as a record set to a uniqueness validator like so:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, conditions: -> { where(confirmed: true) }
```

Then it will only enforce uniqueness against confirmed records.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless

Comment: While you could do this it isn't particularly efficient. You may want to add what you would put in the `if` method to this answer.